# Error loading Python for VS Code IntelliCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Whenever I load up Python in Visual Studio Code, it tells me that something went wrong activating VS IntelliCode support. When I check the "Python" output window, there are several errors. I have replaced all instances of my user folder's name with "defaultuser" for privacy reasons.

```
User belongs to experiment group 'ShowPlayIcon - start'
User belongs to experiment group 'ShowExtensionSurveyPrompt - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'DebugAdapterFactory - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'PtvsdWheels37 - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'UseTerminalToGetActivatedEnvVars - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'LocalZMQKernel - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'CollectLSRequestTiming - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'CollectNodeLSRequestTiming - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'EnableIPyWidgets - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'RunByLine - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'CustomEditorSupport - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'pythonaa'
User belongs to experiment group 'pythonSendEntireLineToREPL'
> conda --version
> conda info --json
> pyenv root
> python3.7 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3.6 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python2 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> /usr/local/bin/python3 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: Failed to get interpreter information for '/usr/local/bin/python2.6' [Error: Command failed: "/usr/local/bin/python2.6" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_path'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:664:12)] {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"/usr/local/bin/python2.6" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"'
}
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: Failed to get interpreter information for '/usr/local/bin/python' [Error: Command failed: "/usr/local/bin/python" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_path'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:664:12)] {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"/usr/local/bin/python" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"'
}
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: Failed to get interpreter information for '/usr/bin/python2.6' [Error: Command failed: "/usr/bin/python2.6" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_path'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:664:12)] {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"/usr/bin/python2.6" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"'
}
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: Failed to get interpreter information for '/usr/local/bin/python2.6' [Error: Command failed: "/usr/local/bin/python2.6" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_path'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:664:12)] {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"/usr/local/bin/python2.6" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"'
}
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: Failed to get interpreter information for '/usr/local/bin/python' [Error: Command failed: "/usr/local/bin/python" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_path'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:664:12)] {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"/usr/local/bin/python" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"'
}
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: Failed to get interpreter information for '/usr/bin/python2.6' [Error: Command failed: "/usr/bin/python2.6" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_path'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:664:12)] {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"/usr/bin/python2.6" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"'
}
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: Failed to get interpreter information for '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python' [Error: Command failed: "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py", line 30, in <module>
    runpy.run_path(module, run_name="__main__")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run_path'

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:304:12)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:430:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:664:12)] {
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  cmd: '"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py" "/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/pythonFiles/interpreterInfo.py"'
}
Starting Jedi Python language engine.
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: Failed to activate a workspace, Class name = y, completed in 3283ms, has a falsy return value, Arg 1: <Uri:/Users/defaultuser/Documents/William's Documents/Computer programs/Experiment with stuff_Py>, Return Value: undefined [Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: Symbol(ILanguageServerActivator)
 Symbol(ILanguageServerActivator) - named: Jedi 

    at /Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:261016
    at m (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:261313)
    at e (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:261804)
    at Object.t.plan (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:262467)
    at /Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:259121
    at e._get (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:259030)
    at e.getTagged (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:257832)
    at e.getNamed (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:257924)
    at a.get (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:39:917230)
    at _.createRefCountedServer (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:32:30661)
    at async _.activate (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:32:28522)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
    at async y.activateWorkspace (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:32:23604)]
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: Failure during activation. [Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: Symbol(ILanguageServerActivator)
 Symbol(ILanguageServerActivator) - named: Jedi 

    at /Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:261016
    at m (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:261313)
    at e (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:261804)
    at Object.t.plan (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:262467)
    at /Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:259121
    at e._get (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:259030)
    at e.getTagged (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:257832)
    at e.getNamed (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:257924)
    at a.get (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:39:917230)
    at _.createRefCountedServer (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:32:30661)
    at async _.activate (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:32:28522)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
    at async y.activateWorkspace (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:32:23604)]
Error 2020-12-14 20:15:44: sendStartupTelemetry() failed. [Error: No matching bindings found for serviceIdentifier: Symbol(ILanguageServerActivator)
 Symbol(ILanguageServerActivator) - named: Jedi 

    at /Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:261016
    at m (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:261313)
    at e (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:261804)
    at Object.t.plan (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:262467)
    at /Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:259121
    at e._get (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:259030)
    at e.getTagged (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:257832)
    at e.getNamed (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:24:257924)
    at a.get (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:39:917230)
    at _.createRefCountedServer (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:32:30661)
    at async _.activate (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:32:28522)
    at async Promise.all (index 4)
    at async y.activateWorkspace (/Users/defaultuser/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2020.11.371526539/out/client/extension.js:32:23604)]
> pyenv root
> pyenv root
Python interpreter path: /usr/local/bin/python3
> pyenv root
> pyenv root
> pyenv root
> pyenv root
> pyenv root
> pyenv root
> pyenv root
```

Those are some very weird and complicated errors, and I don't know how to deal with them so I can get VS IntelliCode working for Python. Perhaps you guys can make sense of all of this? (BTW, I'm using VS Code on a Mac with Microsoft's Python extension and version 3.9.0 of the Python interpreter.)

~ Dec.15 EDIT: I think it's worth mentioning I'm using macOS Yosemite (v10.10). ~

Comment: Yup. Just started for me too. Python 3.8.2 on Arch Linux.

Comment: Seems snap was not giving me the latest version. I was on 1.50, and I needed 1.51

Comment: @William Powell -Since the IntelliSense function of Python is provided by the Python extension, please try to reinstall the Python extension and disable unrelated extensions, and then reload VSCode.

Comment: Manually updating VScode, as @TheBrewmaster suggested, worked for me on Ubuntu.  Seems MS broke backward compatibility in their IntelliSense plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I'm from the Python extension for VS Code team. I'm sorry for this frustration. Updating VS Code to a version that is >= 1.51 should fix the issue.

We're aware of this problem and we're tracking it here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/15237.

Comment: Thanks, the only thing is that I am no longer working on my grandmother's Mac which the issue originated from. I am now working on my own Dell PC in which another issue originates: when I try to compile a C program via Clang using a task, I get this weird error message: `spawn C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe ENOENT`. However, the next time I use my grandmother's Mac, it should auto-update VS Code and the issue regarding Python should be resolved.